# CMD+Shift+D not working – now replaced with CMD+D (even worse)

Tags: keyboard, finder, shortcut

I noticed that in some Apps, in file dialogues, CMD+Shift+D - for "Go to Desktop" - stopped working.

I tried to create a "App Shortcut" that 'clicks' on the Word Desktop with that (custom) shortcut - via the Shortcuts / Keyboard panel. The effect was that now, in my finder, the Shortcut for "Go to Destkop" is "CMD-D" (which is even worse, as that should be 'Duplicate'). Any ideas are welcome on how to go back to where I was before. ;-)

Thank you!
Fabian

[image: current problem, part 2]

Comment: Have a look in **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **App Shortcuts** and see it there is an entry for **Finder** > **Documents**, or (or **Go->Documents**) set to **⌘D**, and if so change it back to: **⇧⌘D**

Answer (score 1):

First, kindly check your setting from **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** and see if <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> has been mapped to anything.

You may also Restore Default if you want to reset everything.

Comment: RE: "**System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Keyboard Shortcuts**" -- The is no such location as   **Keyboard Shortcuts** in at that _path_ in **macOS**, at least not in any version of **macOS**, **macOS Sierra**  thru **macOS Big Sur**.

Comment: @user3439894 I had no issue finding that location in System Preferences, although it is titled "Shortcuts" not "Keyboard Shortcuts"

Comment: @Ezekiel Elin, I'm so glad you had no problem finding the right place, neither did I! The reason I posted a comment  is that unless it has been changed in the upcoming **macOS Monterey**, then what's posted is not correctly stated!

Comment: @user3439894 The instructions are correct though - you can also find them here, under "Customize keyboard shortcuts" https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/keyboard-shortcuts-mchlp2262/mac

Comment: @Ezekiel Elin, I don't know what your problem is but don't ping me again! If you saw my comment to the OP, it states the only place in the **macOS** GUI that the **Finder** > **Go** > **Documents** _keyboard shortcut_ could have been changed from its default of **⇧⌘D** and is certainly more prudent then just clicking the **Restore Defaults** _button_ as mentioned in this answer!

Comment: I was replying to your post saying that you could not find "System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts" in macOS Sierra through macOS Big Sur. I was not addressing anything else  I hope that clears the confusion